# Attribute table trailing zeroes missing in Print Composer

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

I have QGIS 2.18.3 installed. I'm trying to create a printable .pdf map with QGIS Print Composer. It needs to have X & Y coordinates listed in an attribute table, with 3 decimals accuracy.

Print Composer has a separate button for "Add attribute table". I added the table using this feature, but found out, that it looses the trailing zeroes after my coordinate decimals.

For example, the original data has X-coordinate listed as "6818424.020", but Print Composers "Add attribute table" feature lists that same coordinate like this "6818424.02".

It is required for my work to display coordinates with 3-decimals accuracy. I could not find any option to add trailing zeroes at any precision, not to mention with 3 decimals.

Is there any way to change how (with what accuracy) trailing zeroes are displayed in Print Composers attribute table? I know this is possible in Arcmap (which I have no access to at the moment), but cant find this in QGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the *Attributes* option for your table (red circle), click the *Expression* icon (blue circle) and use the **format_number** function:

```
format_number( fieldName, 3 )
```

This should truncate your values to 3 decimal places:

[image: Example]

[image: Result]

---

If you do not want the thousand separator (which occurs when using `format_number`), you can include the `replace` function:

```
replace(format_number(reals, 3 ), ',', '')
```

[image: Result_2]

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem completely! A colleague of mine just asked about thousands separator, whether or not it could be removed. Now I know that too! Many thanks!

Comment: @Gifupack - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)

Comment: Hi! I have a little follow-up question to this. I noticed, there was no comma as thousands separator, but it was done with space "X= 6 835 189,999" and "Y= 24 490 740,986". Don't know if that's related to computer settings or not. But what would be correct way to type the replace function, to prevent spaces from appearing?  ( "X= 6 835 189,999" --->  "X= 6835189,999")  It must be something like: replace(format_number(reals, 3 )xxxxxxxxxx)?

Comment: @Sisuaski Hello! I'm guessing it's a computer or locale (language) setting but you could try `replace(format_number(reals, 3 ), ' ', '')`. Note the space in `' '` which is what you want to replace with.

Comment: For some reason that does not seem to work on spaces between thousands. I tried to use space and tab between  ' ', but neither removed thousands separators. If I'd use only the original data values, coordinates are without thousand separator, but are also missing trailing zeros. Format_number seems to add separators.... I wonder is there any other string, which would do the same as format_number, but without adding thousands separator. Thank you for your help in any case!

Comment: @Sisuaski - Try using `reals || 0` to add one trailing zero to your original value; `reals || 0 || 0` for two trailing zeros etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried your previous tip, it worked on some extent and did not on some. I kind of solved this the "not-so-smart" way, that works for now in my local work. However it does not work when handling data from Oracle DB, which I don't have access to create new tables. I created two new TEXT fields to my shapefile and calculated coordinates with 3 decimals to those text fields. These numbers / trailing zeros that are stored as "text" do not get removed automatically. This works as a test, but for the future, lets hope they add "amount of trailing zeros" -function etc. :)